# How to specify JVM maximum heap size "-Xmx" for running an application with "run" action in SBT?

Tags: scala, sbt

My application does large data arrays processing and needs more memory than JVM gives by default. I know in Java it's specified by "-Xmx" option. How do I set SBT up to use particular "-Xmx" value to run an application with "run" action?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this:

```
class ForkRun(info: ProjectInfo) extends DefaultProject(info) {
    override def fork = Some(new ForkScalaRun {
        override def runJVMOptions = super.runJVMOptions ++ Seq("-Xmx512m")
        override def scalaJars = Seq(buildLibraryJar.asFile, buildCompilerJar.asFile)
    })
}
```

Comment: This is outdated, now you can use `javaOptions += "-Xmx1G"`

Comment: @iwein the content of my post seems to be very important to you.

Comment: Note that `javaOptions` only have effect for forked JVMs (see http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Forking.html)

Comment: Add `fork in run := ture`  enables `javaOptions`

Comment: @coanor this answer is for an ancient version of sbt. There is an answer with much higher rankings just under this one. This answer was the correct answer at the time when the question was asked.

Answer (score 123):

**For forked processes you should look at Build.scala**

To modify the java options for forked processes you need to specify them in the Build.scala (or whatever you've named your build) like this:

```
val buildSettings = Defaults.defaultSettings ++ Seq(
   //…
   javaOptions += "-Xmx1G",
   //…
)
```

This will give you the proper options without modifying JAVA_OPTS globally, *and* it will put custom JAVA_OPTS in an [sbt generated start-script](https://github.com/typesafehub/xsbt-start-script-plugin)

For **non forked** processes it's most convenient to set the config via `sbtopts` or `sbtconfig` depending on your sbt version.

Since sbt 0.13.6 [`.sbtconfig` is deprecated](https://medium.com/@jan______/sbtconfig-is-deprecated-650d6ff10236). Modify `/usr/local/etc/sbtopts` along these lines:

```
-J-Xms512M
-J-Xmx3536M
-J-Xss1M
-J-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
-J-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-J-XX:MaxPermSize=724M
-J-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005
```

**You can also** create an `.sbtopts` file in the root of your SBT project using the same syntax as in the `/usr/local/etc/sbtopts` file. This makes the project self-contained.

**Before sbt 0.13.6** you could set the options in .sbtconfig for **non forked** processes:

1. Check where sbt is:

   ```
   $ which sbt
   /usr/local/bin/sbt
   ```
2. Look at the contents:

   ```
   $ cat /usr/local/bin/sbt
   #!/bin/sh
   test -f ~/.sbtconfig && . ~/.sbtconfig
   exec java ${SBT_OPTS} -jar /usr/local/Cellar/sbt/0.12.1/libexec/sbt-launch.jar "$@"
   ```
3. Set the correct jvm options to prevent OOM (both regular and PermGen):

   ```
   $ cat ~/.sbtconfig
   SBT_OPTS="-Xms512M -Xmx3536M -Xss1M 
    -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled 
    -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:MaxPermSize=724M"
   ```

If you want to set SBT_OPTS only for the current run of sbt you can use `env SBT_OPTS=".." sbt` as suggested by Googol Shan. Or you can use the option added in Sbt 12: `sbt -mem 2048`. This gets unwieldy for longer lists of options, but it might help if you have different projects with different needs.

Note that CMSClassUnloadingEnabled in concert with UseConcMarkSweepGC helps keep the PermGen space clean, but depending on what frameworks you use you might have an actual leak on PermGen, which eventually forces a restart.

Comment: @iwein - The javaOptions did not change the default heapspace for sbt. I checked in jconsole and it just shows -Xmx512M. Even if I add the SBT_OPTS in ~/.sbtconfig, I still get this in jconsole: -Xmx512M -Xms256M -Xmx1G -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC. Do you see the Xmx512 up in the front? It some how doesn't pick the javaOptions from Build.scala. Any pointers?

Comment: @Anand perhaps things are working slightly differently in 0.13? I'll update the answer if I bump into anything (might take a while), let me know if you figure it out in the mean time.

Comment: @iwein I just used the following in my Build.scala and it worked. fork in run := true,
    javaOptions in run ++= Seq("-Xms256m", "-Xmx2048m", "-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC"). See this post for the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27372468/sbt-specify-java-heap-size-in-build-scala/27373101#comment43198372_27373101. Thanks!

Comment: FYI you can also create a `.sbtopts` file in the root of your SBT project using the same syntax as in the `/usr/local/etc/sbtopts` file. This makes your project self-contained, which can be very handy in CI situations.

Comment: On Windows using 0.13.9 (might be 0.13.6) the file is C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\conf\sbtconfig.txt. By default the file had "-Xmx512M" in it without the -J shown in this answer. I can confirm that this file is being read by the fact that sbt assembly issues a warning regarding -XX:MaxPermSize and when I change that value the warning shows the value I entered and not the "256m" value it showed originally.

Comment: Can someone please provide information for inspecting these settings? What is the fastest find to find out if sbt actually picked those up?

Comment: I found them through the Java VisualVM but I'm sure there is a faster way, through SBT itself somehow. Is there?

Comment: Talking to myself here, but this is what I was looking for: -XshowSettings:vm

Answer (score 75):

In sbt version 12 onwards there is an option for this:

```
$sbt -mem 2048
```

Comment: on win 8.1, this command did not work for me: `Not a valid command: mem (similar: set)`

Answer (score 46):

If you run sbt on linux shell, you can use:

```
env JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx512m" sbt run
```

This is my usually used command to run my sbt project.

Comment: Thank you very much. A cool command to know. I never knew of that "env" and missed such a tool many times.

Comment: Hmm, this didn't work for me! I needed the `override def fork` solution above. (sbt 0.7.7)

Comment: it is possible that your sbt file specifies its own JAVA_OPTS, in which case these will be overwritten.  You can then just directly modify your sbt file, either to remove the -Xmx flag or to switch it to your desired maximum heap size.

Comment: I don't think `env` is required

Answer (score 24):

`.sbtconfig` is deprecated starting with SBT `0.13.6`. Instead, I configured these options in `/usr/local/etc/sbtopts` in the following way:

```
-J-Xms512M
-J-Xmx3536M
-J-Xss1M
-J-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
-J-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-J-XX:MaxPermSize=724M
-J-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005
```

Comment: `-J-Xss1M` is a bit low for large case classes, 4M seems to be safer.

Answer (score 7):

There's one way I know of. Set the environment variable JAVA_OPTS.

```
JAVA_OPTS='-Xmx512m'
```

I have not found a way to do this as a command parameter.

Answer (score 7):

Use JAVA_OPTS for setting with environment variable.

Use -J-X options to sbt for individual options, e.g. -J-Xmx2048 -J-XX:MaxPermSize=512

Newer versions of sbt have a "-mem" option.

Answer (score 5):

The `javaOptions += "-XX:MaxPermSize=1024"` in our build.sbt as referenced by @iwein above worked for us when we were seeing a java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown while running Specs2 tests through sbt.

Comment: @UwePlonus it does answer the question.

Answer (score 3):

The environment variable is _JAVA_OPTIONS, which needs to be set.
Once you set _JAVA_OPTIONS, and when you sbt, sbt will show the message using JAVA_OPTIONS and the values.

Alternatively you could set javaOption in the sbt or .scala file
e.g

```
javaOptions += "-Xmx1G"
```

From sbt shell you could run show javaOptions to see the values that are set.

Answer (score 2):

sbt lets you list the JVM options you need to run your project on a file named

.jvmopts

in the root of your project.
then add the java options that you want

```
cat .jvmopts
-Xms512M
-Xmx4096M
-Xss2M
-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=1024M
```

it is tested and works in windows 10
https://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/1.4.x/scala/JVMMemoryOnDev.html

Answer (score 1):

```
    javaOptions in Test += "-Xmx1G"
```

This sets the JVM options for tests. Works also with jvm forking (`fork in Test := true`).

Comment: where is this set in the `build.sbt` ?

Comment: Anywhere, if you have a 1-module project. The order of definitions does not generally matter in SBT. If you have multiple modules, specify this either on some of them or, if you want, globally via `javaOptions in ThisBuild += "-Xmx1G"` or `javaOptions in (ThisBuild, Test) += "-Xmx1G"`