# SBT stop run without exiting

Tags: scala, sbt, terminate

How do you terminate a run in SBT without exiting?

I'm trying CTRL+C but it exits SBT. Is there a way to only exit the running application while keeping SBT open?

Comment: `Ctrl+D` does not work.

Comment: I think `Ctrl + D` works only for Play framework.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

In the default configuration, your runs happen in the same JVM that sbt is running, so you can't easily kill them separately.

If you do your run in a separate, forked JVM, as described at [Forking](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Forking), then you can kill that JVM (by any means your operating system offers) without affecting sbt's JVM:

```
run / fork := true
```

Comment: I'm trying to do this. Specifically, I've implemented: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3868863/how-to-specify-jvm-maximum-heap-size-xmx-for-running-an-application-with-run/4054152#4054152 but sbt still exits when I do CTRL+C. How do I kill just the forked JVM?

Comment: with `kill` from the command line, or in the Task Manager (Windows), or Force Quit or Activity Monitor (Mac OS X), etc.

Comment: After forking, to kill everything java except sbt, run: `kill -9 \`ps -h | grep java | grep -v sbt-launch | grep -v grep | awk '{print $1}'\``

Comment: I love this idea, but it doesn't seem to help.  I'm running sbt 0.13.1 and adding this line into my build.sbt file..

Comment: you need to kill the `run` with CTRL+D

Comment: control-D doesn't help for me in my scenario - no response. The fork in run option is an interesting workaround -- I would prefer the simplicity of being able to use control-c.

Answer (score 85):

From sbt version 0.13.5 you can add to your build.sbt

```
cancelable in Global := true
```

It is defined as "Enables (true) or disables (false) the ability to interrupt task execution with CTRL+C." in the [Keys definition](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/sxr/sbt/Keys.scala.html)

If you are using Scala 2.12.7+ you can also cancel the compilation with CTRL+C. Reference https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/6479

There are some bugs reported:

- https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/1442
- https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/1855

Answer (score 9):

I've found the following useful when I have control over the main loop of the application being run from sbt.

I tell sbt to fork when running the application (in build.sbt):

```
fork in run := true
```

I also tell sbt to forward stdin from the sbt shell to the application (in build.sbt):

```
connectInput in run := true
```

Finally, in the main thread of the application, I wait for end-of-file on stdin and then shutdown the JVM:

```
while (System.in.read() != -1) {}
logger.warn("Received end-of-file on stdin. Exiting")
// optional shutdown code here
System.exit(0)
```

Of course, you can use any thread to read stdin and shutdown, not just the main thread.

Finally, start sbt, optionally switch to the subproject you want to run, run.

Now, when you want to stop the process, close its stdin by typing CTRL-D in the sbt shell.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [sbt-revolver](https://github.com/spray/sbt-revolver). We use it in our company and it's really handy. 
For what you're asking can be done with:

```
reStart

reStop
```

Without need to configure build.sbt file.

Your can use this plugin by adding:

```
addSbtPlugin("io.spray" % "sbt-revolver" % "0.9.1")
```

To your project/plugins.sbt

Comment: does not work for me