# Issue Running Shapeless in REPL

Tags: scala, shapeless

Given the following SBT files:

```
$cat shapeless_sandbox/build.sbt
name := "shapeless sandbox"

scalaVersion := "2.11.5"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.chuusai" %% "shapeless" % "2.1.0-RC1"
)

resolvers ++= Seq(
  Resolver.sonatypeRepo("releases"),
  Resolver.sonatypeRepo("snapshots")
)

// Fork JVM when `run`-ing SBT
// http://stackoverflow.com/a/5265162/409976
fork in run := true
```

And the SBT version:

```
$cat shapeless_sandbox/project/build.properties
sbt.version=0.13.7
```

Running `sbt`, `update`, and then `console`, I can't run the examples from the [Feature Overview](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#polymorphic-function-values).

```
scala> import poly._
<console>:7: error: not found: value poly
       import poly._
              ^
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

When you check out the Shapeless repository and launch a REPL from that directory, [this command](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/shapeless-2.1.0-RC1/project/Build.scala#L184) (from the SBT build configuration) will be executed:

```
initialCommands in console := """import shapeless._"""
```

If you're simply depending on Shapeless in your own project, you won't get the same effect. You could add this line to your build, but it's much more common just to import `shapeless._` manually when you start the REPL. Once you've done that, `import poly._` (which is a relative import for the contents of the `shapeless.poly` package) will work just fine.