# how to get control-c to kill only the running process and not sbt itself?

Tags: libgdx, sbt

Putting the finishing touches on my dev environment with libgdx and Scala SBT, I'm trying to make control-c kill the running process but *not* SBT itself. Here is the scenario:

- load sbt into the interactice prompt
- while in the interactive prompt, invoke the game using the following libgdx style syntax:

`> desktop/run`

This loads my game and spawns the screen. However, when I press control-C, not only is the game stopped, but SBT exits as well.

How can I have SBT exit the currently running process but keep the interactive sbt build shell running?

Thanks!

Comment: I have marked it as duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5137460/1553233). Let me know if I am off on this.

Comment: man! I got docked two points for a duplicate question. sheesh :P