# Shut down Akka HTTP app

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

I have a running Akka HTTP application and I want to shut it down.

Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> in SBT [does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5137460/sbt-stop-run-without-exiting) for me (my shell is currently Git Bash for Windows).

What's the recommended way of shutting down an Akka app gracefully?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Taking inspiration from [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/akka-user/6Pv591rC7pU), I added a route to my application that shuts down the application:

```
def shutdownRoute: Route = path("shutdown") {
  Http().shutdownAllConnectionPools() andThen { case _ => system.terminate() }
  complete("Shutting down app")
}
```

where `system` is the app's [ActorSystem](https://doc.akka.io//docs/akka/current/general/actor-systems.html).

Given this route, I can now shut down my application with

```
curl http://localhost:5000/shutdown
```

---

**Edit:**

Being able to shut down a server remotely is not a good idea for production code. In the comments, [Henrik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5397096/henrik) pointed to a different way that shuts down the server by hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> in the SBT console:

```
StdIn.readLine()
// Unbind from the port and shut down when done
bindingFuture
  .flatMap(_.unbind())
  .onComplete(_ => system.terminate())
```

---

For context, I put the above code at the end of server initialization:

```
// Gets the host and a port from the configuration
val host = system.settings.config.getString("http.host")
val port = system.settings.config.getInt("http.port")

implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

// bindAndHandle requires an implicit ExecutionContext
implicit val ec = system.dispatcher

import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directives._
val route = path("hi") {
  complete("How's it going?")
}

// Starts the HTTP server
val bindingFuture: Future[ServerBinding] =
  Http().bindAndHandle(route, host, port)

val log = Logging(system.eventStream, "my-application")

bindingFuture.onComplete {
  case Success(serverBinding) =>
    log.info(s"Server bound to ${serverBinding.localAddress}")

  case Failure(ex) =>
    log.error(ex, "Failed to bind to {}:{}!", host, port)
    system.terminate()
}

log.info("Press enter key to stop...")
// Let the application run until we press the enter key
StdIn.readLine()
// Unbind from the port and shut down when done
bindingFuture
  .flatMap(_.unbind())
  .onComplete(_ => system.terminate())
```

Comment: In this example they show a similar way to exit, using the same method call, but by pressing return instead of opening a connection. May be preferable if you have easy physical access to the machine it's running on.
http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/scala/http/routing-dsl/index.html#minimal-example