# How to set heap size for sbt?

Tags: scala, sbt

I am using SBT 0.12.0. I have read other answers on stack overflow and followed them, however none of them helps, for example:

- create `ForkRun` class - I have not observed any forked process during my usage of sbt
- set environment variable `JAVA_OPTS` - it is set but sbt's process command line does not seem to use it at all.
- `sbt -J-Xmx2G` appends the parameter to sbt process command line, however the old value `-Xmx1536m` is used by sbt instead of the appended parameter.

Am I missing something? How do I set heap size for sbt 0.12, when doing both testing and `run`?

Comment: Have you tried `mem` parameter when you starting sbt? (e.g. `sbt -mem2000`)

Comment: You might have a typo, it should be JAVA_OPTS not JAVA_OPS

Comment: Check out my answer to a duplicate of this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3868863/how-to-specify-jvm-maximum-heap-size-xmx-for-running-an-application-with-run/14561346#14561346 the marked answer there is wrong, but mine works (sometimes you need to check comments/votes too :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I have found the solution. No matter how you specify JVM heap size, it will never work because SBT executable already has it overridden.

There is a line in SBT executable which says:

`. /usr/share/sbt/sbt-launch-lib.bash`

So I edited the file:

```
  # run sbt
  execRunner "$java_cmd" \
    ${SBT_OPTS:-$default_sbt_opts} \
-   $(get_mem_opts $sbt_mem) \
    ${java_opts} \
    ${java_args[@]} \
    -jar "$sbt_jar" \
    "${sbt_commands[@]}" \
    "${residual_args[@]}"
```

Remove the `-` line.

Now when you run SBT, it will no longer override your JVM heap size settings. You can specify heap size settings using @Noan's answer.

Or alternatively:

`sbt -J-Xmx4G -J-Xms4G`

Comment: Actually it seems that `export SBT_OPTS="..."` in `~/.sbtconfig` does work indeed.

Comment: from SBT 0.13.6 on ```.sbtconfig``` file is deprecated

Answer (score 110):

You need `SBT_OPTS`, here's what I use in my *.bash_profile*:

```
export SBT_OPTS="-Xmx1536M -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:MaxPermSize=2G -Xss2M  -Duser.timezone=GMT"
```

**UPDATE:**
To get your 2G heap space you can use this:

```
export SBT_OPTS="-Xmx2G -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:MaxPermSize=2G -Xss2M  -Duser.timezone=GMT"
```

**NOTE: SBT MUST BE LATEST VERSION**

Older versions of `sbt` contain bugs that override these settings, use `brew upgrade sbt` for latest `sbt` for Mac (assuming brew install) (IDK for Linux). https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/2945#issuecomment-277490848

Comment: Thank you. It indeed changes sbt process command line as expected, however the old `-Xmx1546m` still exists in the command line and max heap size is still capped at 1.5 GB, as shown in visualvm.

Comment: any way to set this environment setting in the SBT config that's source-controlled?

Comment: Take a look at scalaz source, they have a bash file called sbt that loads everything they need aka is environment specific https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/series/7.2.x/sbt

Comment: I get a warning: `Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=4G; support was removed in 8.0`

Comment: @samthebest Perm Gen was basically removed in Java 8 so it's not necessary to include this.

Comment: why did you add timezone=GMT?

Comment: This is what I use for my profile and we run everything in GMT regardless of physical location.

Comment: I added `export SBT_OPTS="-Xmx4G -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -Xss2M -XX:MaxPermSize=512M"` to my `~/.bash_profile; . ~/.bash_profile`, but I'm getting an `Out of Memory: heap space` error upon compilation: `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`

Answer (score 74):

As of March 2015, if you are using sbt on **OSX** with **Homebrew** then you should edit the file `/usr/local/etc/sbtopts`

e.g.

```
# set memory options
#
#-mem   <integer>
-mem 2048
```

Comment: This seems to also work well for windows, instead of having to mess around with env variables (the file is under c:\program files\sbt\confs).

Comment: In Linux it's in `/etc/sbt-launcher-packaging`.

Comment: In Ubuntu Artful, I found it in `/etc/sbt/sbtopts`

Comment: This solution will make the JVM preallocate all 2GB memory. If you use `SBT_OPTS=-Xmx2G sbt` to start SBT, it will grow the heap as needed up to a maximum of 2GB.

Comment: Have a look at @mike s solution above: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55706960/1199564

Answer (score 47):

"sbt -mem 23000 run" works for me.

Comment: thats 23Gb isn't it..?

Comment: @BenHutchison this is probably paulp's sbt wrapper, not the original sbt is it

Answer (score 18):

A quick way to do it is with a `.jvmopts` file in the root of your project (from the [Lagom Framework documentation](https://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/latest/scala/JVMMemoryOnDev.html)):

```
 $ cat .jvmopts
 -Xms512M
 -Xmx4096M
 -Xss2M
 -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=1024M
```

Then if you want to check that you have set correctly run `sbt -verbose`

Comment: This should be the marked as the correct answer as it also allows per project settings.

Comment: Indeed this answer should be accepted because it can be committed along with the project.

Answer (score 15):

On windows, for sbt 0.13.9.2, you need to set `JAVA_OPTS` to the jvm options you want.

```
> set JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx1G
> sbt assembly
```

The `sbt.bat` script loads its defaults from `conf\sbtconfig.txt` into `CFG_OPTS` but will use `JAVA_OPTS` instead if set.

Relevant excerpts from `sbt.bat`:

```
rem FIRST we load the config file of extra options.
set FN=%SBT_HOME%\..\conf\sbtconfig.txt
set CFG_OPTS=
FOR /F "tokens=* eol=# usebackq delims=" %%i IN ("%FN%") DO (
  set DO_NOT_REUSE_ME=%%i
  rem ZOMG (Part #2) WE use !! here to delay the expansion of
  rem CFG_OPTS, otherwise it remains "" for this loop.
  set CFG_OPTS=!CFG_OPTS! !DO_NOT_REUSE_ME!
)
```

. . . (skip) . . .

```
rem We use the value of the JAVA_OPTS environment variable if defined, rather than the config.
set _JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS%
if "%_JAVA_OPTS%"=="" set _JAVA_OPTS=%CFG_OPTS%
:run
"%_JAVACMD%" %_JAVA_OPTS% %SBT_OPTS% -cp "%SBT_HOME%sbt-launch.jar" xsbt.boot.Boot %*
```

Answer (score 11):

I was looking to solve a problem like this on Mac OS X with a homebrew install of SBT. If you installed SBT via homebrew, you're in the clear since the `/usr/local/bin/sbt` file looks like

```
#!/bin/sh
test -f ~/.sbtconfig && . ~/.sbtconfig
exec java -Xmx512M ${SBT_OPTS} -jar /usr/local/Cellar/sbt/0.12.3/libexec/sbt-launch.jar "$@"
```

This means that any settings you put in `SBT_OPTS` will stick (your -Xmx will take precedence). Furthermore, the first line of the script will execute any commands in `~/.sbtconfig` if it exists so it may be a better place to put your SBT options if you are playing with them quite a bit. You won't have to `source ~/.bash_profile` every time you make a change to `SBT_OPTS`

Comment: yes. This is what I have in $HOME/.sbtconfig. export SBT_OPTS="-XX:MaxPermSize=512M -Xmx2G -Xms64M" and when i start sbt, I do a ps aux and it displays /usr/bin/java -Xmx512M -XX:MaxPermSize=512M -Xmx2G -Xms64M -jar /usr/local/Cellar/sbt/0.13.0/libexec/sbt-launch.jar

Comment: However, I just saw the answer below and perhaps that launcher is for another type of setup. My setup is specific to Mac using the homebrew package.

Comment: Homebrew SBT now requires the heap size to be configured with `-mem` parameter in `/usr/local/etc/sbtopts`

Answer (score 7):

If running sbt from PowerShell, set the `SBT_OPTs` environment variable, like so:

```
$env:SBT_OPTS="-Xms512M -Xmx1024M -Xss2M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=1024M"
```

Then run:

```
sbt
```

Answer (score 7):

For SBT version 1.0.4 **on Windows** the default **JVM settings come from `sbt\conf\sbtconfig.txt`** file. Simply edit the values here. Change `-Xmx512M` to `-Xmx2048M`.

This is not the only source of JVM options for SBT. Others can be found by inspecting `sbt.bat`. A simple way to diagnose, where do the settings come from, is by commenting out this line in batch file: `@echo off`.

Comment: Note: this `sbt\conf` is placed not in the user directory, but in the Program Files folder, like `C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\conf`.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the configuration of my service was overwriting the environment variable `SBT_OPTS` and `JAVA_OPTS`. I was able to set the limits by setting in my `build.sbt` the following:

```
javaOptions in Universal ++= Seq(
  "-J-Xms1g",
  "-J-Xmx2g")
```

Reference: https://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/archetypes/java_app/customize.html

Answer (score 0):

On windows, running `SET SBT_OPTS="-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:MaxPermSize=2G -Xmx2G -Xms1G"` before `sbt` seems to be what solved it for me.

Reference: https://www.baeldung.com/scala/sbt-heap-size

I just changed `export` to `SET`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Windows, you can easily set as environment variables:

[image]

Afterward, don't forget to restart your terminal prompt (CMD, Powershell,...) to refresh.

This does work for me!