# scala - bash: hw.scala: Permission denied

Tags: java, scala, sbt, filenotfoundexception

I installed scala with sbt according this post [Getting started](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Setup).

But when I created easy start project [Hello world](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Hello.html) I met weird output:

```
nazar_art@nazar-desctop:~$ find .sbt
.sbt
.sbt/.lib
.sbt/.lib/0.12.1
.sbt/.lib/0.12.1/sbt-launch.jar
.sbt/boot
.sbt/boot/update.log
nazar_art@nazar-desctop:~$ cd hello
nazar_art@nazar-desctop:~/hello$ echo 'object Hi { def main(args: Array[String]) = println("Hi!") }' > hw.scala
bash: hw.scala: Permission denied
nazar_art@nazar-desctop:~/hello$ sbt
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/nazar_art/.sbt/boot/update.log (Permission denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:212)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:165)
    at java.io.FileWriter.<init>(FileWriter.java:90)
    at xsbt.boot.Update.<init>(Checks.java:51)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.update(Launch.scala:266)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$jnaLoader$1.apply(Launch.scala:111)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:108)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.jnaLoader$2f324eef(Launch.scala:106)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.<init>(Launch.scala:85)
    at xsbt.boot.Launcher$.apply(Launch.scala:281)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:16)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:31)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:20)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
Error during sbt execution: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/nazar_art/.sbt/boot/update.log (Permission denied)
```

I can't understand why this happen coz I'm `su`.
Any suggestions.

**EDIT:**

I used `chmod 777` for update.log. 
But now when I try to run sbt I have:

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 63 Aug 13 11:17 hw.scala
nazar_art@nazar-desctop:~/hello$ sudo echo 'object Hi { def main(args: Array[String]) = println("Hi!") }' > hw.scala
nazar_art@nazar-desctop:~/hello$ sbt
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
```

- ***How to solve this trouble?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does 'ls -l ~/.sbt/boot' return?

Comment: It returns `-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Aug 13 10:42 update.log`

Comment: Take ownership of it: su chown -R nazar_art ~/.sbt

Comment: For your new issue, try decreasing the heap size to 1G per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15280839/how-to-set-heap-size-for-sbt

Comment: Any luck with that? I'm a bit skeptical just because sbt was running in the JVM prior to the permissions change, albeit with IO errors. Maybe try running sbt as su since root owns everything.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you resolved your first question. For the 2nd error you've got, please add

export SBT_OPTS="-Xmx2G"

and retry(change 2G part as you want depends on your dev enviroment). Sbt complaint about lack of JVM heap size, so you need to increase those.