# How to set the PermSize for scalatest-maven-plugin?

Tags: java, maven, memory, jvm, scalatest

We're using scalatest-maven-plugin to run some spark tests, and the default perm size is around 80M, which is not enough, so we often got "OutOfMemoryError: PermGen".

I tried to give it a bigger size, but not found how to configure it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `argLine` config parameter as documented here  http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_the_scalatest_maven_plugin

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
  <artifactId>scalatest-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <configuration>
    <reportsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/surefire-reports</reportsDirectory>
    <junitxml>.</junitxml>
    <filereports>WDF TestSuite.txt</filereports>
    <argLine>-XX:MaxPermSize=128m</argLine>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>test</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>test</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```