# Out of memory error Error while building spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt

I am building spark by using sbt. When I run the following command:

```
sbt/sbt assembly
```

it takes some time to build spark. There are several warning that appear and at the end I am getting following errors:

```
[error] java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.
```

When I check sbt version using command **sbt sbtVersion**, I get following result:

```
[warn] Multiple resolvers having different access mechanism configured with same name 'sbt-plugin-releases'. To avoid conflict, Remove duplicate project resolvers (`resolvers`) or rename publishing resolver (`publishTo`).
[warn] There may be incompatibilities among your library dependencies.
[warn] Here are some of the libraries that were evicted:
[warn]  * com.typesafe.sbt:sbt-git:0.6.1 -> 0.6.2
[warn]  * com.typesafe.sbt:sbt-site:0.7.0 -> 0.7.1
.......
[info] streaming-zeromq/*:sbtVersion
[info]  0.13.7
[info] repl/*:sbtVersion
[info]  0.13.7
[info] spark/*:sbtVersion
[info]  0.13.7
```

When I give command, **./bin/spark-shell**, I get following output:

```
ls: cannot access '/home/neel_shah/spark/spark-1.6.1/assembly/target/scala-2.10': No such file or directory
Failed to find Spark assembly in /home/neel_shah/spark/spark-1.6.1/assembly/target/scala-2.10.
You need to build Spark before running this program.
```

What can the solution be?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You must configure SBT heap size:

- on linux type `export SBT_OPTS="-Xmx2G"` to set it temporary
- on linux you can edit `~/.bash_profile` and add line `export SBT_OPTS="-Xmx2G"`
- on windows type `set JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx2G` to set it temporary
- on windows you can edit `sbt\conf\sbtconfig.txt` and set `-Xmx2G`

More info:

http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.1/docs/Getting-Started/Setup.html

[How to set heap size for sbt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15280839/how-to-set-heap-size-for-sbt)

Comment: When I do this (in windows) i get: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0. Not sure what to do now?

Comment: PermSize is a different memory area. You can ignore this message, it is only a warning.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not a common resolution, but in my case I had to run this command to resolve the OutOfMemoryError when building a spark project with sbt (path is specific to mac OS):

```
rm -rf /Users/markus.braasch/Library/Caches/Coursier/v1/https/
```

Increasing memory settings for a variety of arguments in SBT_OPTS did not solve it.