# SBT and command line parameters in PowerShell problem

Tags: powershell, sbt, windows-10, akka

I try to run in PowerShell: `sbt -mem 6000 compile` which works in bash.

Error: OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space.

Tested on akka compilation. Tried already few combinations with `&` without any success. Works on Ubuntu with PowerShell-core and Bash. Fails on Windows 10.

How to write it properly in PowerShell? Why is it so hard to do such simple thing?

Answer (score -1):

Not a solution, but an easy walkaround is to modify the global config file:

[How to set heap size for sbt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15280839/how-to-set-heap-size-for-sbt/47621495#47621495)