# sbt, "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space"

Tags: java, scala, sbt

I'm trying to replicate the openie4.0 program by:
https://github.com/knowitall/openie

The environment is
Ubuntu: 18.04,
Scala: 2.10.2,
Java: 1.7.0_80,
sbt: 0.13.18,

I managed to get to the step of "running with sbt:"
'''
sbt 'run-main edu.knowitall.openie.OpenIECli'
'''

However, I kept facing with the problem of

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

when I step into to create the stand-alone jar, when using:

```
sbt clean compile assembly
```

while trying
"sbt -J-Xmx2700M clean compile assembly" (or larger, say 10g, I have 64g on my computer)
The above out of memeory problem continues plus:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
[error] Not a valid command: J-Xmx10g
[error] Not a valid project ID: J-Xmx10g
[error] Expected ':' (if selecting a configuration)
[error] Not a valid key: J-Xmx10g
[error] J-Xmx10g
[error]
```

This is super confusing why this command isn't a valid one and I didn't find a solution for this.

Later on I tried to set the universal JAVA_OPTS, not working.
Then I take the suggestions from  user972946 (last one), which suggest its overriden since the default settings.
[How to set heap size for sbt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15280839/how-to-set-heap-size-for-sbt).

Then trying after fixing as he suggested,but still the same.....

```
env JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx41200m" sbt clean compile assembly
```

I also took the suggestion from Mike and Cassio from the above link...not working at all.

Really appreciate on any suggestions on this.

Many thanks.
HZ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a look at the following line:

```
[error] Not a valid command: J-Xmx10g
```

Your sbt cannot resolve this as a valid option, this can be issued since you're using java 7 (make sure java7 accepts `-Xmx$size` as a valid argument), the same thing goes for sbt 0.13 (which is pretty old). there also must be a file or something related to deployments (a guide or a CI/CD file or something) that you can take help from on how to run the project. (if you use java 8 everything should be fine probably)

Comment: Aminmal, thanks for your answer. I finnally find it's because the local setting of sbt is cofigured at the installing process...so I go back to that file and changed the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Baeldung:](https://www.baeldung.com/scala/sbt-heap-size)

Try exporting this environment variable before running it:

`export SBT_OPTS="-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:MaxPermSize=10G -Xmx10G -Xms10G"`

Alternatively, SBT allows us to specify the JVM options on a file named `.jvmopts`. create a file called `.jvmopts` in the root of your project and put this inside:

```
-Xms1g
-Xmx4g
```