# wsl: sbt, ivy configuration

Tags: sbt, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ivy

I have sbt installed on my windows machine, and I have set SBT_OPTS with:

> -Dsbt.ivy.home=C:/var/.ivy2
> -Dsbt.global.base=C:/var/.sbt/
> -Dsbt.repository.config=C:/var/.sbt/repositories

I want to have similar setup in WSL, but am not able to find where in wsl are these configured.

Where do I need to look for it in WSL to set in SBT_OPTS?

Answer (score 0):

I don't use SBT, so I could be way off base here, but it appears from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15281562/11810933) that `SBT_OPTS` is simply an environment variable.  Typically you will simply configure that in Linux (and WSL) by either:

- One-time:

  ```
  export SBT_OPTS="-D/home/username/.ivy2 ..."
  ```
- Or so that it loads automatically by placing the same line in your `~/.bash_profile`

Of course, you'll need to set all the paths to their WSL/Linux locations.