# How to increase the heap size used by a .zip distribution created via "sbt dist"?

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm using a package built on sbt, and following the instruction, which is: run
`sbt dist` in the package folder.

After the process, i got a .zip file that contains the bin file if i unzip it. (Windows system)

However, I'd like to increase the heap size/memory allocated for this package/program.

I've tried all methods as listed below, but none of them worked.

I've searched a lot, including all methods listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15280839/how-to-set-heap-size-for-sbt). But seems like they use sbt directly, like sbt run, sbt project_name, etc, which are not very related to my problem i guess?

Thank you all for the comments! Here is the link to the documentation about how to "Build and Link" of the project I tried to use https://github.com/anskarl/LoMRF/blob/develop/docs/7_1_build_and_link_lomrf.md

Comment: The heap size is not hardcoded in a program, rather when you run it you can specify that property.

Comment: How do you run the program given the zip file? I guess there's a file like a `.bat` or something like that that runs `java` under the hood. You'll want to customize this file.

Comment: You should give us more details as what SBT plugins you are using that does the "DIST" part. For example sbt-pack allows customisation directly from `build.sbt` (https://github.com/xerial/sbt-pack) but I assume that's not what you are using.

Answer (score 0):

The author of that project answered the question and here is the solution: https://github.com/anskarl/LoMRF/issues/24.

For example, to set it to 8GB, run in the shell the following:

LOMRF_JVM_ARGS="-Xmx8g" lomrf