# How to increase available memory for a plugin?

Tags: sbt

Is it possible to allocate more memory for the process running the sbt plugin?

I am getting `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded` for the one of the plugin I am running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this:

```
sbt -mem 8192
```

Comment: You should try to extend your answer by providing more information why this helps.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3868863/how-to-specify-jvm-maximum-heap-size-xmx-for-running-an-application-with-run