# SBT Specify java heap size in Build.scala

Tags: scala, sbt, heap-size

My Build.scala file contents.

```
val commonSettings = Seq(
version := "1.0.0",
organization := "com.collective",
scalaVersion := "2.11.4",
scalacOptions ++= List(
  "-encoding", "UTF-8",
  "-target:jvm-1.7",
  "-feature",
  "-unchecked",
  "-deprecation",
  "-Xlint",
  "-Xfatal-warnings"
),
resolvers ++= Seq(
  "ConJars" at "http://conjars.org/repo"
),
javaOptions in run += "-Xms256M -Xmx2G -XX:MaxPermSize=1024M -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC"
)

lazy val segmentFetcher = Project("segments-fetcher", file("."))
.settings(commonSettings: _*)
)
```

However, when I execute

```
sbt run
```

and look in the jconsole, the heap size I set in the Build.scala is not picked up. It just shows -Xmx512M. Can anyone please let me know how we force sbt to pick the heap space from the project build file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to change the heap size, you need to tell sbt to [fork another JVM](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Forking.html) (this applies to any JVM option by the way). You can use the `fork` setting to do so:

```
fork in run := true
```

Also, you want to make sure, that your options are properly separated (there is no additional parsing done by sbt):

```
javaOptions in run ++= Seq(
    "-Xms256M", "-Xmx2G", "-XX:MaxPermSize=1024M", "-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC")
```

Alternatively, you can set the heap size in the sbt runner. If you are using normal sbt, you can modify the launcher script directly. If you are using sbt-extras, you can pass arguments to the JVM using the `-J` flag:

```
sbt -J-Xmx2G # etc.
```

Comment: when I do fork in run := true,
    javaOptions in run += "-Xms256m -Xmx1024m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC", I get [error] Invalid initial heap size: -Xms256m -Xmx1024m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
[error] Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine

Comment: Oh... didn't realize that your options were wrong (sbt does not parse them into multiple arguments). Updated my answer

Comment: Not a valid command: J-Xms1024M
Not a valid project ID: J-Xms1024M
Expected ':' (if selecting a configuration)
Not a valid key: J-Xms1024M
J-Xms1024M