# Look at Options in `.sbtopts` within Running `sbt`

Tags: sbt

Per this helpful [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14561346/409976), I removed my `~/.sbtconfig`, and added `.sbtopts`:

```
$cd myProject
$cat .sbtopts
-J-Xmx4G
-J-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
-J-XX:MaxPermSize=4G
```

Then I ran `sbt`. How can I, via the `sbt` console, verify those options set in `.sbtopts`?

Comment: Kevin, were you able to get an answer for this?

Answer (score 19):

If you `man sbt`, you'll see that there's a debug flag; so, you'll see something like this:

```
$ sbt -d
[process_args] java_version = '1.7.0_72'
# Executing command line:
java
-Xms1024m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=128m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-jar
/usr/share/sbt-launcher-packaging/bin/sbt-launch.jar
```

Here's my sbtopts file: /usr/share/sbt-launcher-packaging/conf/sbtopts

```
-J-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
-J-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be valid sbt option.

Comment: ditto what marios mentioned: sbt -d results in a warning "The `-` command is deprecated in favor of `onFailure` and will be removed in 0.14.0"

Comment: Still works OK in 2022 with sbt 1.6.2

Comment: Alternatively: sbt -v (sbt --verbose) - prints the same info about args without following debug clutter.

Answer (score 5):

Latest versions of the jdk comes with a nice tool called `jps` that tells you about running java processes

`jps -v` should point you to the processes and show the passed-in options

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if you can do it from within the sbt console but you can add `-J-XX:+PrintFlagsFinal` to `.sbtopts` and the JVM will print all the flags.