# StackOverflowError with Scala on IntelliJ

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea

I am trying to build a Scala project on IntelliJ using Gradle. I am able to make but compile keeps failing with a stack overflow error.

I looked through other posts with similar issues which suggested increasing heap/stack size ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34318705/stackoverflowerror-in-sbt-during-compile) and [this](https://github.com/ucb-bar/firrtl/issues/66)). So far I have tried setting these in JAVA_OPTS and idea64.exe.vmoptions.

> -Xss512m -Xms512m -Xmx2048m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=64m -ea

I also tried including -XX:MaxPermSize=2048m which didn't work either (believe it is not supported in Java 8 anyway).

The same code builds for another person with the same configuration. Can anyone please shed some light on what I am missing?

Details:

```
IntelliJ Ultimate 2016.1
Scala 2.10.3
Java 1.8.0_92
```

Stack Trace:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$Eraser.typed1(Erasure.scala:696)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$96.apply(Typers.scala:4523)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$96.apply(Typers.scala:4523)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.silent(Typers.scala:680)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.normalTypedApply$1(Typers.scala:4522)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedApply$1(Typers.scala:4578)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInAnyMode$1(Typers.scala:5343)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5360)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$Eraser.typed1(Erasure.scala:696)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedQualifier(Typers.scala:5472)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedQualifier(Typers.scala:5480)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$Eraser.adaptMember(Erasure.scala:642)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$Eraser.typed1(Erasure.scala:696)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$96.apply(Typers.scala:4523)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$96.apply(Typers.scala:4523)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.silent(Typers.scala:680)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.normalTypedApply$1(Typers.scala:4522)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedApply$1(Typers.scala:4578)
```

Comment: This exception is from the compiler process, not the process of IDEA itself. Try to increase -Xss in 

Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> Scala Compile Server -> JVM Parameters.

Also check that Scala compile server is enabled.

Answer (score 20):

The exception is from the compiler that IntelliJ employs, hence you need to change the *compiler build process'* heap size. Go to

```
File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler -> Build process 
heap size (Mbytes)
```

Increase this property to a higher value.

[image: Screenshot showing the settings pane increasing the value to 1024 MBytes]

Answer (score 20):

I've solved this via:

Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler -> Scala Compiler -> Scala Compile Server

And updated JVM options to use a bigger stack size, eg: `-Xss8m`

Restart for the changes to take effect.

Answer (score 4):

Adding -Xss100m in eclipse.ini worked in my case, probably adding similar property in intellijJ may help.

Comment: I have raised similar question on below link, please follow that:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46110844/scala-compiler-stackoverflow-error-when-importing-project?noredirect=1#comment79185015_46110844

Comment: 100m for stack seems excessive!

Answer (score 2):

Here is what worked for me:

- From Windows Powershell, $env:SBT_OPTS="-Xss1024m"
  and then ran sbt compile
- Also in IntelliJ v2020.2, following also worked:
  Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> SBT
  -> JVM : VM Parameters : -Xss1024m

Answer (score 0):

I had same issues and done lots changes in intellij but non of them work.

I removed `unused case classes` from my code and its working

Answer (score 0):

For those poor souls who as me searched all over the internet and could not find a working solution. In my case: updating libraries and Scala to the latest version didn't help; changing changing a stack size using -Xss didn't help; reducing the nesting level of case classes didn't help; restarting Gradle daemon didn't help. I had few case classes with few dozens of fields, some had nested case classes. I found out that it might be related to case classes and removed unnecessary fields in a test case class in a file that couldn't compile and that finally resolved the issue.