# Scala compiler StackOverflow Error when importing project

Tags: scala, sbt

I am importing a Scala project after building it using sbt, in sbt library dependencies are json4s-native & json4s-jackson...

After building the project using sbt eclipse while importing it in Eclipse it gives following error:

Error in Scala compiler
java.lang.StackOverflowError

This screen comes:

[image: This screen comes]

& then this:

[image: & then this:]

Scala version: 2.11.7

Log:

```
!ENTRY org.scala-ide.sdt.core 4 0 2017-09-08 12:42:02.495 !MESSAGE Error in Scala compiler
!STACK 0
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.checkDead(Typers.sc‌​ala:111) 
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedSelectOrSuperC‌​all$1(Typers.scala:4‌​812)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInAnyMode$1(Ty‌​pers.scala:5344)
```

Comment: See _Error Log_ view for detail (stack tracke). Since it is an issue of the Scale compiler, which Scala version do you use and with which code does the error occur (show us a [minimal, complete, and cerifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))?

Answer (score 3):

Adding following parameter to eclipse.ini worked:
-Xss100m

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a Scala compiler bug (not Eclipse related):

- **Update Scala** since some [`StackOverflowError` bugs of the Scala compiler have already been fixed since version 2.11.7](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-10020?jql=status%20%3D%20CLOSED%20AND%20fixVersion%20in%20(%22Scala%202.11.8%22%2C%20%22Scala%202.12.0%22%2C%20%22Scala%202.12.0-M1%22%2C%20%22Scala%202.12.0-M2%22%2C%20%22Scala%202.12.0-M3%22%2C%20%22Scala%202.12.0-M4%22%2C%20%22Scala%202.12.0-M5%22%2C%20%22Scala%202.12.0-RC1%22%2C%20%22Scala%202.12.0-RC2%22%2C%20%22Scala%202.12.1%22%2C%20%22Scala%202.12.2%22%2C%20%22Scala%202.12.3%22)%20AND%20text%20~%20%22stackoverflowerror%22)
- If updating Scala does not help, you have to find out which code causes the error and how to avoid it (see [open Scala `StackOverflowError` bugs](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7612?jql=status%20%3D%20Open%20AND%20text%20~%20%22stackoverflowerror%22)).

Comment: Updated error is:

Throwable during asyncExec
java.lang.StackOverflowError

Comment: Que) Can case class not have more then 22 parameters? 
Ans) It seems in scala old versions it was restriction, but in 2.11.7 it is not an issue