# sbt ignoring the commandline options? (windows)

Tags: scala, sbt

I am running

```
sbt compile
```

for a compiling a program. I am getting the

```
OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Exception. Instead I tried

```
sbt compile -J-Xms4G -J-Xmx6G
```

But I don't see any difference in memory usage of the program, like ignoring the command-line options, and I get the same exception (and when crashing it is barely using 0.8GB).

Comment: See this answer about setting `SBT_OPTS` - http://stackoverflow.com/a/14561346/390708

Comment: To check settings in effect use `jconsole` or similar tool. It has `VM Summary` page that displays stuff like this: `VM arguments: 
-Xmx256M -Xms32M -D...`