# SBT increase compilation memory

Tags: scala, sbt

How can I increase the compilation memory for the project in the build.sbt? Not in the general SBT config.

I want the config to be committed into my Git repo.

Cheers

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3868863/how-to-specify-jvm-maximum-heap-size-xmx-for-running-an-application-with-run

Comment: This applies to running the app with more memory. I am looking to COMPILE with more memory.

Comment: I don't think so. Unless you specify `javaOptions in run += "-Xmx8G"` (so with `in run`). Give it a try.

Comment: That didn't work even with `fork := true`

Comment: the stackoverflow solution linked above is a java VM runtime solution and not a compiler "scalac" solution. It also does not apply to the modern Scala 11 and 12 versions that use SBT to build (which is the context of the original posters "how do I do this in build.sbt" requirement)

Comment: "javaoptions in run is also a VM not a javac compiler" solution.

Comment: the suggested solution is to do this:

Answer (score 4):

[Create `.sbtopts` file in root of your SBT project and put in `-J-Xmx4G` (and similarly `-J<JVM option>`.](https://medium.com/@jan______/sbtconfig-is-deprecated-650d6ff10236) Unfortunately, [it doesn't seem to work on Windows](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-launcher-package/issues/92).

Comment: That's what I experienced too. Thanks for the bug report

Answer (score 0):

the apparent solution would be to do it this way:

```
scalacOptions in ThisBuild ++= Seq ("-JXss512m","-JXmx2G")
```

while I see these values display when I run:
sbt
show scalacOptions

the settings do not seem to be honored by the actual compiler