# Customizing ForkJoinPool in sbt application

Tags: java, java-8, sbt, forkjoinpool

As describe in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html for customizing `ForkJoinPool ThreadFactory` I need to start java with extra parameter `java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.threadFactory=MyThreadFactory`

But when the application starts by the sbt firstly start jvm for sbt. And when jvm start it tries to create ForkJoinPool with `MyThreadFactory.class` which does not exist in this phase.

Secondly, sbt start application inside available jvm. Now `MyThreadFactory.class` available for loading but initialization `ForkJoinPool` already finished in the previous phase.

So my question is How to customize default ForkJoinPool in sbt application.

Comment: what is `sbt` btw?

Comment: @Eugene Looks like it's [this one](https://www.scala-sbt.org/)

Comment: [this helps may be?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3868863/how-to-specify-jvm-maximum-heap-size-xmx-for-running-an-application-with-run)

Comment: sbt is scala build tool