# Cannot seem to run Play application in a forked JVM from within SBT

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

I have a *Scala Play Framework* web-application (using *Scala* v2.13.7 and *Play* v2.8.8) built using *SBT* (v1.5.5).

My `build.sbt` includes the following:

```scala
lazy val root = (project in file("."))
.enablePlugins(PlayScala)
.settings(

  // etc.

  fork := true,
  javaOptions ++= Seq(
    "-Xms1G",
    "-Xmx8G",
  ),
)
```

However, a separate JVM for the web-application is not spawned when I execute `sbt run`, and the memory settings are those of the SBT JVM (`-Xms1024m` and `-Xmx1024m`).

Does the *PlayScala* plugin interfere with or disable forking when running the web-application itself? Can I force the web-application to use a forked JVM from within *SBT*?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the sbt documentation, [Forked JVM Options](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Forking.html#Forked+JVM+options), you may want to do something like:

```scala
lazy val root = (project in file("."))
.enablePlugins(PlayScala)
.settings(

  // etc.

  javaOptions ++= Seq(
    "-Xms1G",
    "-Xmx8G",
  ),
  fork := true,
  run / javaOptions += "-Xms1G -Xmx8G",
)
```

I'm not very familiar with play, but this should resolve the issue you're facing.

Comment: It seems that you're recommending adding a `run / javaOptions` setting, correct? The problem is that a forked process is not created, despite the `fork := true` setting, so this change makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Sparing myself a long investigation on my part, **if** all you want to do is affect java options, set them (all in one or one per line is ok) in a file named `.jvmopts` in the sbt project root folder (-as [mentioned elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50557943/23023) already).

Comment: I realize I can do that, but the problem is that I'm unable to create a forked process, despite `forked := true` being present in the _SBT_ build. The _Java_ options were just to add flavor to the problem as presented here, but I do need the web-application to be forked when it runs.